# C# multithreaded code access to local variables inside a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

My question has to do with the following bit of code. I simplified the code to distill the question.

I understand that the lock keeps the foo Hashtable variable from being changed, but what about the variable outside the lock? We're seeing some odd behavior in code that looks like this and this was the question that came up. Thanks for any input.

```
using System.Collections;

namespace MultithreadScratch01
{
    public class ThreadFoo
    {
        public void Foo(Stub2 stub2, Hashtable foo)
        {
            Stub1 bar;

            var prop1 = stub2.Prop1;
            var prop2 = stub2.Prop2;
            var prop3 = stub2.Prop3;

            var hash = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", prop1, prop2, prop3);

            lock(foo)
            {
                if(!foo.Contains(hash))
                {
                    bar = new Stub1 {Foo = "some arbitrary string", Bar = 123};
                    foo.Add(hash, bar);
                }
            }

        }
        public class Stub1
        {
            public string Foo { get; set; }
            public int Bar { get; set; }
        }
        public class Stub2
        {
            public string Prop1 { get; set; }
            public string Prop2 { get; set; }
            public string Prop3 { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which "variable outside the lock"?

Comment: I think it may benefit you to describe the "odd behaviour"

Comment: It's in code that I inherited and unfortunately it's a pattern that's been repeated in a few places. The observed odd behavior is incorrectly selected data. As to the variable outside the lock, specifically, I'm thinking the hash variable.

Thanks so much for the quick feedback. I don't have a great deal of experience with multithreaded code and have generally avoided it when I can, but I did think this was a bit smelly. I just couldn't place why. This being legacy code, though, means I have get through it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 9):

What you're doing here is a "worst practice" in multiple ways.

First off, there is no guarantee whatsoever that other threads that have reference to that hash table are also locking it before they read or write it.  That's why this technique is so bad; it is difficult to make that guarantee.

Second, there is no guarantee whatsoever that other threads that have reference to that hash table instance are not locking it *and failing to unlock it* because they are buggy or hostile. You are potentially putting other people in charge of the correctness of your code, and that is a dangerous position to be in. A good rule is "never lock anything that external code can see". Never lock "this", never lock a Type object, and so on. There are times to make an exception to that rule, but I would want a good reason.

The right thing to do here is to use a ConcurrentDictionary in the first place. If you can't do that, then I would write a wrapper around HashTable:

```
sealed class ThreadSafeHashTable
{
    private readonly HashTable hashTable = new HashTable();
    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        lock(this.hashTable)
        {
            ...
```

Now the locking is (1) always done every time Add is called, and (2) only the code in this class can possibly take the lock, because the object that is locked is private and never passed out.

Only if you could not do either of those things would I do this the hard way. If you want to do it the hard way then you are going to have to track down **every single place the hash table could possibly be used** and ensure that the correct locking code is written.

Comment: Agreed. Interestingly, though, the VS 2003 documentation says otherwise: "Typically, expression will either be this, ..., or typeof(class)..." Can it be updated, or is old documentation locked? (see what I did there..?)

Comment: That is unfortunate! I'll mention it to the documentation manager, but yes, typically we do not revise documentation that is that old.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't quite true to say that the `lock`

> keeps the foo Hashtable variable from being changed

simply; no two threads locking on the same object can be inside the lock at the same time. If you have any code that **doesn't** `lock` on the same object (the hash-table), it will walk right in and could well cause damage. Re the other variables... if anything is mutating the *objects*, and isn't locking on the same lock object that you are, things could get funky. Actually, there are even some edge-cases if it *is* locking on the same object (that would be solved my moving the property-reads **inside** the `lock`). However, since those variables aren't "captured", once you have a snapshot of the values the snapshot will not change.

Answer (score 3):

You are somewhat mistaken on what the lock is doing.  It is not preventing other threads from accessing or modifying `foo`, but it is actually preventing other threads from entering the code block the lock surrounds.  If you are modifying `foo` elsewhere, you might see issues.

Since `hash` is a local variable, you shouldn't see any problems with it.

You might want to try using a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead of a `Hashtable`, it is designed for multi-threaded access.

Comment: Actually, it should be noted that `Hashtable` is designed for multi-thread access too (unlike `Dictionary<,>`, which really isn't) - the distinction being that `Hashtable` is thread-safe for any number of readers and **at most** one writer - meaning: writers must synchronize, but readers do not need to.

Comment: That's true.  Been a while since I've used one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Locking on a parameter is a dangerous game as the guys above have alluded to since you don't know what is being done with that parameter outside of your method.  Someone else could be modifying it at the same time.

You could wrap all the code in your method to make sure only one thread is in that code at a time, but since your Stub1 and Stub2 classes aren't thread safe (need to put locks on the properties) then even doing that wouldn't guarantee that the properties aren't being changed while you're reading them.