# C# multithreaded code issue corrupting data

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

This is really really close to the real method that [Bob posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704128/c-sharp-multithreaded-code-access-to-local-variables-inside-a-lock/9704626#9704626)  What we have are templates that are being merge with specific data.  The code below is trying to reuse the templates that we have already built.  So if we have already built a template for "Dallas" we can reuse it.  What we are seeing is the template for "Dallas" having the information the template for "NewYork" should have.  When we step through the code slowly we don't see it.  My thought is that the variable **sc** below is being changed by another thread before it gets put into the hash table **genericTemplates** so when the thread working with the Dallas information is ready to insert the information into the **genericTemplaes** hashtable the thread working with NewYork has already change the data held within **sc** to reflex the NewYork data but is stamped with the Dallas "recordHash" key.   Like Bob, I am new to using the Lock statement and understanding how it really works.

I was also told that any variables that are within the scope of the thread only pertain to that thread.  It is only global variables or objects passed in that I need to be looking at. Could someone verify that.

```
private Template EnsureGenericTemplate(Detail details, Hashtable genericTemplates)
{
    Template return_Object = null;
    SectionContainer sc = null;
    StringBuilder htmlTemplate = null;
    string recordHash = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", circleNumber, zipCode, topicCd);

    lock (genericTemplates) {
        hasTemplateDefined = genericTemplates.ContainsKey(recordHash);
    {

    if (!hasTemplateDefined)
    {
        templateData = getTemplateData();

        htmlTemplate = new StringBuilder(foo1.HtmlTemplate);

        HtmlParser = hp = new HtmlParser();
        sc = hp.parseNew(htmlTemplate.ToString(), false);

        //This method merges the html template with the template data based on <tags>
        htmlTemplate = BuildTemplate(sc, htmlTemplate.ToString(), templateData);

        //This method merges the html template with the template data base on %SomeVar%
        hp.parseProperties<Detail>(ref htmlTemplate, details, false);

        //Puts the htmlTemplate into an object that hold html and text
        foo2.Html = htmlTemplate.ToString();

        lock (genericTemplates)
        {
            if (!genericTemplates.ContainsKey(recordHash))
            {
                  return_Object = new Template(foo2, sc);
                  genericTemplates.Add(recordHash, Object_For_Reuse);
            }
        }
    }  

    if (htmlTemplate == null)
    {
        lock (genericTemplates)
        {
            if (genericTemplates.ContainsKey(recordHash))
                return_Object = (Template)genericTemplates[recordHash];
        }
    }
    return return_Object;
 }
```

Comment: Don't EVER use lock on an object which is likely to change. If you want to use a lock properly, create an Object which you then use solely for locks. Its a common mistake.

So Object lockMe = new Object(); - and make sure its static.

Comment: Not sure your example contains enough detail to spot the problem. You seem to have 3 lock statements. After the first, `hasTemplateDefined` could be set to false, then another thread could define the template, then your current thread would enter the block guarded by `if (!hasTemplateDefined)`. I don't know if that in itself would cause a problem, but the guard is not "safe".

Answer (score 3):

You are locking twice on `genericTemplates` - that's unnecessary.

Instead of using `Hashtable` consider using a collection that is design for multi-threading, like `ConcurrentDictionary`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

I would also suggest reading this free book about multi-threading - it's full of good patterns

http://www.albahari.com/threading/